# datatable Hide columns on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm tryng to hibe datatable columns clicking a list changing the size font of link

```
Toggle column: <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="0" id="tog-vis-00">ID</a> - 
               <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="1" id="tog-vis-01">Position</a> - 
               <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="2" id="tog-vis-02">Office</a> - 
               <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="3" id="tog-vis-03">Age</a> - 
               <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="4" id="tog-vis-04">Start date</a> - 
               <a class="toggle-vis" data-column="5" id="tog-vis-05">Salary</a>
```

and the JQuery for hide/unhide columns is

```
$('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        DrawHideColum();

    } );
```

My Function "DrawHideColum" change the font size of the text for easy found hidden columns in the list.

```
function DrawHideColum(){
    if (table.columns(0).visible().join(', ') === 'true'){
        $('#tog-vis-00').css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $('#tog-vis-00').css("font-weight", "normal");
    }
    if (table.columns(1).visible().join(', ') === 'true'){
        $('#tog-vis-01').css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $('#tog-vis-01').css("font-weight", "normal");
    }
    ......
}
```

If I have 100 columns how to use DrawHideColum dinamically??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason for -1 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably have not exposed the question correctly but the function at the end is this...

```
function DrawHideColum(){         
        var n = 0;

        table.columns().visible().each( function() {
            if (table.columns(n).visible().join(', ') === 'true'){
                $('a[data-column="' + n + '"]').css("font-weight","bold");
            } else {
                $('a[data-column="' + n + '"]').css("font-weight","normal");
            }
            n++;
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly all you need is to change the font-weight attribute of the clicked element. You can do this in one function:

```
$('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
    column.visible(!column.visible());

    if(column.visible()) {
        $(e.target).css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $(e.target).css("font-weight","normal");
    }
});
```

You can add some CSS classes, e.g.: visible-column and hidden-column. Then it's easy to call [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function to replace the ugly *if-else* statement:

```
$('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
    column.visible(!column.visible());

    $(e.target).toggleClass("visible-column","hidden-column");
});
```

Use this piece of code to automatically set CSS properties of all columns:

```
$('a.toggle-vis').each(function(){
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

    if(column.visible()) {
        $(e.target).css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $(e.target).css("font-weight","normal");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is OK but work only after a click. I set "stateSave": true in my table and if I refresh the page the font-weight is "normal".
I need something to set the css for a.toggle-vis on load. Thanks

Comment: @MadCat see the updated answer. This piece of code will update all of the columns.